# what is difference between the square of an operator and the expectation value of that operator

Tags: complex-numbers, differential-operators, compact-operators

operator $\hat A$ is a mathematical rule that when applied to a ket $\hat A|\phi\rangle$ transforms it into another ket $\hat A|\phi '\rangle $ and too for bra.

$\langle \phi| \hat A|\phi\rangle$  for short  $\langle\hat A\rangle$

1. what is the square of item $\langle\hat A\rangle^2$ ?
2. what is the expectation value item $\langle\hat A^2\rangle$?
3. what is difference between them$\Delta A=\sqrt{\langle\hat A^2\rangle-\langle\hat A\rangle^2}$?

Comment: Is this a question about mathematics, or about understanding quantum mechanics? If mathematics, then what kind of answer to "what is ..." do you expect? The expressions are what they are -- which other description than that do you imagine getting?

Comment: @Henning Makholm


what ever you like explain it.

Comment: The point is I don't think there _is_ any explanation that doesn't just repeat the expression you want explained. $\langle \hat A\rangle^2$ is the number $\langle \hat A\rangle$ multiplied by itself. That seems to be all there is to say about it, absent any knowledge of $\hat A$ or $\phi$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm

i need mathematical proof
For Example
$|z|+|z'|\ge |z+z'|$
mathematical proof is:
$(xy'-x'y)^2\ge 0$
some thing like this.

Comment: You need mathematical proof of _what_? "Multiplied by itself" is what "$^2$" _means_. That's not a matter of proof, it is just how the notation works.

Comment: @Henning Makholm

proof that there is difference between then
them

Comment: Well, if we take $\hat A$ to be the identity operator on $\mathbb R^1$ and $\phi$ to be $2$, then $\langle \phi|\hat A|\phi\rangle^2=16$ but $\langle \phi|\hat A^2|\phi\rangle=4$. That looks pretty different.

Comment: @Henning Makholm
assume $\hat A=complex\,number$

Comment: $1$ is a perfectly cromulent complex number!

Comment: @Henning Makholm
and $\Delta A$ will be complex too.
isn't that ture!?

Comment: cross-post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24207/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Uncertainty Relation Between  Two Operators**

An interesting application of the commutator algebra is to derive a general relation giving the uncertainties product of two operator $\hat A$ and $\hat B$

if  $\langle\hat A\rangle$ and  $\langle\hat B\rangle$ be the expectation valus of to hermitian operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ with respect to a normalized state vector $|\psi\rangle$. that is, $\langle \psi| \hat A|\psi\rangle=\langle\hat A\rangle$  and $\langle \psi| \hat B|\psi\rangle=\langle\hat B\rangle$

The uncertainties $\delta A$ and $\delta B$ are defined by:

$$\delta A=\sqrt {\langle\hat A^2\rangle - \langle\hat A\rangle^2}$$,
$$\delta B=\sqrt {\langle\hat B^2\rangle - \langle\hat B\rangle^2}$$,
$$\delta A \delta B\ge \frac {1}{2}|\langle [\hat A, \hat B] \rangle|$$

leads to [Heisenberg Uncertainty Relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)

$$\Delta x \Delta p_x \ge \frac {1}{2}|\langle [\hat X, \hat P_x] \rangle|=\frac {1}{2} |\langle i\hbar \hat I \rangle|=\frac {1}{2} \hbar$$